# How to query by BinData subtype?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection which had been storing LUUIDs (legacy UUIDs, BinData subtype 0x03), and the application storing the values has recently made a change to start storing standard UUIDs of BinData subtype 0x04.

I'm looking for a way to execute a `find` query that will return all records that have the BinData subtype 0x03 UUIDs.

I read through https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/ and it seems the granularity of the `$type` expression only allow querying for `"binData"` but not by binData subtypes.

I'm trying to do something like `db.getCollection('myCollection').find({field: { $type: "binData3" }})` Which of course is invalid because `binData3` is not a valid type alias, only `binData` is.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you want to convert the data, there are multiple answers on this site showing how to do that. For querying, how are you intending to provide the binary values, assuming you were able to specify the subtype?

Comment: I'm not intending to provide the values. That's the whole point of my question. If I had the binary values I could just find by `BinData(3, value)` I'm trying to find all BinData types with subtype of 3, or all values that are Legacy UUIDs as opposed to standard.

Comment: I think you'll need to get all binaries and deal with them in the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB [comparison/sort order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/index.html#bindata) compares binary data in 3 steps:

1. First, the length or size of the data.
2. Then, by the BSON one-byte subtype.
3. Finally, by the data, performing a byte-by-byte comparison.

Since legacy and current UUIDs are the same length, you could search from the null UUID in type 3 to the null UUID in type 4, like:

```
db.collection.find({ field: { 
                      $gte: BinData(3,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=="), 
                      $lt: UUID("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") 
}})
```