# Is that possible to convert records that have standard GUID representation to UUID representation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection where the _id fields in that collection are stored in 2 different ways:

1. `BinData(3,"ABCD123")`
2. `UUID('9cac87c9-02a5-123a-abcd-123456789abc')`

Is that possible that I find all the documents that have BinData and change it to UUID format or even find BinData documents and remove it?

Comment: Both are BinData. Subtype '3' is the legacy UUID. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65922070/convert-bindata-type-3-data-to-type-4-in-mongodb

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66426027/how-to-query-by-bindata-subtype